# Ruby On Rails Nokogiri gem importing orders from xml working not fully. Possibly permitted perimeters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having some trouble with Nokogiri.

I'm new to this xml parsing and I seem to get no errors. I get the order imported alert.

Which means it may be permitted perimeters. If I'm right then, Could I create a model that allows all permitted perimeters. So please take a look, thank you for your time, here is my code:

Routes.rb

```
resources :orders do
  collection { post :import }
  get "/confirm" => "confirmations#show"
  get 'dconfirmation' => 'orders#confirmation'
end
```

Model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  scope :not_completed_orders, -> {
    where(:complete => false)
  }
  require 'nokogiri'

 def self.import(file)
    doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(file)
    #your processing code goes here
 end
end
```

Controller Order

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  def create
    @order = current_user.orders.new(order_params)
    @order.email = current_user.email
    @order.name = current_user.name
    @order.address_line_1 = current_user.address_line_1
    @order.address_line_2 = current_user.address_line_2
    @order.postcode = current_user.postcode
    @order.city = current_user.city
    @order.country = current_user.country
    if @order.save
      redirect_to dconfirmation_path
    end
  end

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).
      permit(
        :email,
        :delivery_name,
        :company_name,
        :delivery_address1,
        :delivery_address2,
        :delivery_address3,
        :delivery_city,
        :delivery_postcode,
        :delivery_country,
        :phone,
        :package_contents,
        :description_content,
        :restricted_items,
        :terms_conditions,
        :insurance,
        :contents_value,
        :cf_reference,
        :reference_number,
        :service
        )
  end
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def confirmation
  end

  def import
    Order.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Order imported."
  end


end
```

View

```
  = form_tag import_orders_path, multipart: true do
    = file_field_tag :file
    = submit_tag "Import"
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question what is going wrong - all you do in your model is create a nokogiri doc, and the there's a comment. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Im trying to import and phrase a XML document. Idealy i would like a way of saving the fields in my msql

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you're failing to open the file, or failing to parse the XML.

Comment: Im failing to phrase the file. However as i said. It doesn't throw a console error so its hard to answer your question. Because it says file imported and i get the nokogiri authentication hey and file translation.